# How to save the additional checkbox in Porto Theme's custom Login form?

Tags: magento2

I'm truly newbie to Magento 2 developer, and I'm currently facing a problem that I can't amazing how to  solve the problem that describes as below:

**The problem:**
I've added a checkbox (Tilmeld nyhedsbrev) in English (Sign Up for Newsletter) into the Porto Theme's login form. Please take a look at the attachment image for further information.

The question is:
If a customer marked the checkbox (checked=true) the click the LOG IND (submit button) button, well, then... how do I save the customer's email into Magento 2 Customer newsletter module database?

**Here is the code for that action:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login $block */
?>
<div class="row">
  <div class="block block-customer-login col-md-6 mx-auto mb-4 w-100">
      <div class="block-title">
          <strong id="block-customer-login-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Registered Customers')) ?></strong>
      </div>
      <div class="block-content" aria-labelledby="block-customer-login-heading">
          <form class="form form-login"
                action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPostActionUrl()) ?>"
                method="post"
                id="login-form"
                data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
              [![enter image description here][1]][1]<?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
              <fieldset class="fieldset login" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
                    <div class="field note"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('If you have an account, sign in with your email address.')) ?></div>

                    <div class="field email required">
                        <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <input name="login[username]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getUsername()) ?>" <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()) : ?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?> id="email" type="email" class="input-text line-height-xl" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" data-mage-init='{"mage/trim-input":{}}' data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field password required">
                        <label for="pass" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password')) ?></span></label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <input name="login[password]" type="password" <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()) : ?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?> class="input-text line-height-xl" id="pass" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password')) ?>" data-validate="{required:true}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
                    <div class="field">
                        <a class="action remind" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getForgotPasswordUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Forgot Your Password?')) ?></span></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="actions-toolbar">
                        <div class="primary"><button type="submit" class="action login primary btn-v-dark py-3 text-md w-100" name="send" id="send2"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign In')) ?></span></button></div>
                        <div class="secondary">
                            <a href="/customer/account/create/" class="action create primary btn-v-dark py-3 text-md w-100"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create an Account')) ?></span></a>
                        </div>
                            
                        <style>
                            .customer-account-login .action.create {
                                display: none;
                            }
                        </style>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field choice login-newsletter">
                        <input 
                            type="checkbox" 
                            name="is_subscribed" 
                            id="login-newsletter" 
                            value="1" 
                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?>"
                            <?php /* default unchecked */?>
                            class="checkbox">
                        <label for="login-newsletter" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?></span></label>
                    </div>
                    
              </fieldset>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `events.xml`

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_observer" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\CustomerLoginObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

2. Now create observer `CustomerLoginObserver.php`

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\CustomerLoginObserver.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerLoginObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // You Can Get Customer Like this
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $customeremail = $customer->getEmail(); 

        // DO YOUR Other things here
    }
}
```